# What does unlimited login mean in salesforce?

Tags: licenses, user-management

Below is one statement -

> The Overage High Volume Customer Portal license is the same as the
>   High Volume Customer Portal license, except that users do not have
>   unlimited logins.

Here what does `unlimited logins` mean? Can anyone please explain?

> Does `unlimited login` indicates that a particular user can login any
>   number of time OR Any number of user can login any number of times?

Answer (score 2):

unlimited logins means all contacts you have in your org will be able to login to Customer Portal. Indirectly (to some extended) its unlimited login to Customer Portal.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Do mean the limit on concurrent user at any given point?

Comment: You will need to contact salesforce.com for information about the number of Customer Portal licenses you can activate for your org

Comment: As per my understanding with "High Volume Customer Portal license" contacts(Customers) can log in any time & with any concurrency. But not with  "Overage High Volume Customer Portal license" If you have question like how many user can login with "Overage High Volume Customer Portal license" then you should reach to SFDC support. hope that helps.

Comment: The licence without unlimited logins means that it is metered; each successful login costs "one login", and once those are all used up, you have to pay for extra successful logins per month. Concurrency isn't the issue; all users can still log in at any time, from any place, and as many people that can access the service at once. The difference between the two is that the unlimited logins allows for very high traffic, while the limited login counter is for a limited amount of traffic.